# trait 'App\HasApiTokens' not found in Lumen

Tags: php, traits, lumen

I am running Lumen (5.6.3) (Laravel Components 5.6.*). I'm trying to build a Rest api using this tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWoJ2YbdrWU&t=5s). Here is my games.php code:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Bican\Roles\Traits\HasRoleAndPermission;
use Bican\Roles\Contracts\HasRoleAndPermission as HasRoleAndPermissionContract;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class games extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthenticatableContract, HasRoleAndPermissionContract
{ 
    use HasApiTokens, Authenticatable, Authorizable;
    protected $table="games";

    protected $fillable = ['Team 1','Team 2','Score 1','Score 2','Game Date','Viewers'];     
}
```

The error I get after running is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'App\HasApiTokens' not found in C:\Users...lumen-api\app\games.php on line 14

Fatal error: Trait 'App\HasApiTokens' not found in C:\Users\...lumen-api\app\games.php on line 14

In games.php line 14:

  Trait 'App\HasApiTokens' not found
```

I did everything the same as the tutorial. I can't solve this error in part 2.

Comment: try         "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",

Answer (score 13):

Do you have composer? Install that first. Then you need Laravel Passport.

1. Run `composer require laravel/passport`
2. Run `php artisan passport:install` from command line
3. Add add the `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` trait to your `App\User` model.

Try again.

Comment: before step 2 
you should run php artisan migrate

Answer (score 3):

You must include this "use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;" at the top in your user model.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens trait to your  App\User model. This trait will provide a few helper methods to your model which allow you to inspect the authenticated user's token and scopes:

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
}
```